# python, словарь

Tags: python, словарь

Допустим имеется словарь mnz = {}, с набором ключей x1, x2, x3, x4, и у каждого есть свои слова. что происходит, если сделать, допустим mnz.update({x1:}), значения удаляться, или останутся теми же?

Comment: Хм... А как насчёт загуглить или проверить? Или вы хотите чтоб это сделали за вас?

Comment: а почему вы не попробуете это сделать самостоятельно?

Answer (score 1):

Произойдёт ошибка `SyntaxError` потому что после `:` пустота